# Java - Unicode input in cmd.exe doesn't match from other languages (like Node)

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, stdin

While reading input from the console via cmd.exe using Java, I noticed that if I input a string with Chinese characters (`你好`), it would always return a 65 (Char code for ?) in place of the character. The characters display correctly inside my terminal.

[image]

I have also set the encoding for the `InputStreamReader` and in `-Dfile.encoding` to UTF-8 (also tried Windows-1252, and it returns the same results).  I used both Java 8 and 17.

Here is the code I used:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String in = reader.readLine();
        String chars = in.codePoints()
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}
```

When I tested with another language (Node.js), it returned the correct set of bytes for the characters I input (`228,189,160,229,165,189`).

Here is the code I used to test in Node.js:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin);

rl.question("", (result) => console.log(new TextEncoder().encode(result).join(",")));
```

How can I get the correct string from stdin?

Comment: What does `chcp` give in cmd.exe?

Comment: @g00se `Active code page: 437`

Comment: It is possible that the characters that you are testing with are interpreted differently (in terms of bytes) this would be true if one console is expecting utf-8 characters and other is using a different text format.

Comment: That's a type of [ASCII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). You could try changing the code page to the utf-8 equivalent but you might be better off trying powershell

Comment: Why don't you remove the `Readers` from System.in and try reading in the bytes as raw bytes?

Comment: @user16320675 I have tried changing the code page, this just turns every character into a null byte (0). And using `System.in.read` returns the same results (65, or 0 with `chcp 65001`.)